# GROUP BY aggregate by column

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

I've run into an issue where every time I attempt to use `GROUP BY`, H2 informs me that I need to add certain column names into the `GROUP BY` clause because, based on my research, it's unclear to H2 how to sort columns with non-repeating data.

Here's an example to elaborate:

**Person table**

```
+------------+------------+
| ID         | Name       |
+============+============+
| 1          | John       |
+------------+------------+
| 2          | Jane       |
+------------+------------+
```

**Pet table**

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID         | PERSON_ID  |    NAME    | BIRTHDATE  |
+============+============+============+============+
| 1          |      1     |  Rufus     |  2012      |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 2          |      1     |  Ben       |  2014      | 
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Let's say I want all the oldest pets belonging to John.

```
SELECT PERSON.NAME, PET.NAME, PET.BIRTHDATE FROM PERSON
INNER JOIN PET ON PET.PERSON_ID = PERSON.ID
GROUP BY PERSON.NAME
ORDER BY PET.BIRTHDATE ASC
```

This would work perfectly in MySQL because it will simply group by `PERSON.NAME` and, by default, select the first record in the set. However, in H2 it needs to have aggregation such as `MAX`, `MIN`, etc.

The problem, as you can see in this example, is that you could use `MIN` to get the `BIRTHDATE` ordered correctly but there does not appear to be any aggregation function available for sorting `NAME` based on the oldest `BIRTHDATE`?

Comment: *This would work perfectly in MySQL because it will simply group by PERSON.NAME and, by default, select the first record in the set*. Actually, according to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html): *In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, __the values chosen are indeterminate__, which is probably not what you want.*  So whatever you may have observed is probably not behavior you can rely on. Just FYI.

Comment: @sstan: Perhaps but in my experience MySQL is pretty good at selecting the best choice. Most of the time it's the record at the top based on my experience so add a bit of ordering and you generally tend to get what you want.

Comment: Yes. I'm just mentioning it because if the documentation says you can't rely on that behavior, then that means that the optimizer could very well decide to do something completely different depending on the circumstances, or the behavior could change between releases. You don't want to be caught with your pants down. As an example, notice one of the [deprecated features in MySQL 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations): *(continued in next comment...*)

Comment: *Relying on implicit `GROUP BY` sorting in MySQL 5.7 is deprecated. To achieve a specific sort order of grouped results, it is preferable to use an explicit `ORDER BY` clause. `GROUP BY` sorting is a MySQL extension that may change in a future release; for example, to make it possible for the optimizer to order groupings in whatever manner it deems most efficient and to avoid the sorting overhead.*

Comment: @sstan: Perhaps, but right now that won't help me

Answer (score 0):

You can always resort to `NOT EXISTS` in such cases, if the person has no pet with smaller birthdate then the pet is the oldest (if two pets happen to have the same age and both are the oldest ones for that person, then both are selected):

```
SELECT p.NAME, q.NAME, q.BIRTHDATE
FROM PERSON p
  INNER JOIN PET q ON q.PERSON_ID = p.ID AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM PET WHERE PERSON_ID = p.ID AND BIRTHDATE < q.BIRTHDATE
  )
ORDER BY q.BIRTHDATE ASC
```

If you insist on `GROUP BY` you can do it like this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, b.BIRTHDATE FROM (
  SELECT p.id, MIN(q.BIRTHDATE) birthdate FROM PERSON p
  INNER JOIN PET q ON q.PERSON_ID = p.ID
  GROUP BY p.ID
) o INNER JOIN PERSON a ON a.ID = o.ID
  INNER JOIN PET b ON b.PERSON_ID = a.ID AND b.BIRTHDATE = o.BIRTHDATE
ORDER BY b.BIRTHDATE
```

If you can use `WITH` the query could be written easier.

Comment: I thought about using nested `SELECT` queries. It might be a good solution but I think my main concern there is around performance when adopting this same principle into bigger queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the oldest pets, I would recommend:

```
SELECT p.NAME, pt.NAME, pt.BIRTHDATE
FROM PERSON p INNER JOIN
     PET pt
     ON pt.PERSON_ID = p.ID
WHERE pt.BIRTHDATE = (SELECT MIN(pt2.BIRTHDATE)
                      FROM pet pt2
                      WHERE  pt2.PERSON_ID = PT.PERSON_ID
                     );
```

This explicitly selects the pet or pets (for each person) that have the earliest birth year.  No aggregation is necessary.

You can also phrase this with `JOIN`s only in the `FROM`:

```
SELECT p.NAME, pt.NAME, pt.BIRTHDATE
FROM PERSON p INNER JOIN
     PET pt
     ON pt.PERSON_ID = p.ID JOIN
     (SELECT PERSON_ID, MIN(pt2.BIRTHDATE) as MINBT
      FROM pet pt2
      GROUP BY pt2.PERSON_ID
     ) pt2
     ON  pt2.PERSON_ID = PT.PERSON_ID;
```

Comment: How will this do in terms of performance if you were to increase the size of the query and data?

Comment: The performance of these queries should be reasonable, even for tables that are reasonably sized.  Of course, the queries will slow down, because the queries require reading all the data.